# Null Pointer Exception with objectinputstream

Tags: java, arrays, input, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to read this list of names and phone numbers in. But the the program keeps throwing nullpointerexception. Why is it doing this?

```
int i=0;
        Datab[] b = null;
         //b = null;

        // The name of the file to open.
        String fileName = "datt.dat";

        try {
            // Use this for reading the data.
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
            FileInputStream FileIS = new FileInputStream("datt.dat");
            ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(FileIS);

            for(i=0; i<b.length; i++)
             b[i]=(Datab)input.readObject();

            input.close();
```

Comment: Where does it throw it? Which line?

Comment: Please provide the exception stack trace. Side note on your code: you are defining a variable with the file name .. just to reuse the same string again (instead of using the string variable that you declared in front of the try block.

Answer (score 1):

b is null, so b.length throws the exception